# clojure convert oracle time stamp to long

Tags: java, clojure, timestamp

In clojure I have an object returned from a sql query.

> object[oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP 0x68c8a61a 2016-10-27 14:36:33.0]

I want to convert it to long. I tried to use `.getTime` but got an error

> IllegalArgumentException No matching field found: getTime for class oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP  clojure.lang.Reflector.getInstanceField (Reflector.java:271)

This has taken me a few hours already. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code you're working with.

Comment: (let [                                                                                                                                            
latest_received (execute-db-sql (str "select max(TIMERECEIVED) as latest_received from tps_trade_messages where id_tps=" id " and id_tps_ver=" (get (first cdo-ver) :cdo_ver) " group by id_tps, id_tps_ver"))                                                                                                                                            ]
;here i want to convert it to long. (println  (get (first latest_received) :latest_received))))))

Answer (score 0):

First convert Oracle `TIMESTAMP` to Java `Date`, then take time from `Date`:

```
(.getTime (.dateValue timestamp))
```